# PHP - Get vector path from image

Tags: php, image, svg, vector, imagick

In PHP is there any way to get / extract vector *coordinates* from image.

following example of svg image, I want to get this image vector path.

[image: svg image with vector path]

I will be using this *vector path* on another image to crop it something like below image

[image]

Comment: SVG is just XML so use an XML parser.

Comment: Why do you think getting the vector path is a required step in this? And are you actually starting with that plain star image - or are you starting with something else.

Comment: @Danack I will be using vector path to crop other images like in second pic showing dog in cropped section. yes, i am starting with star image but it could be any shape.
[example pic](http://freedesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/deer-silhouette.jpg)
imagine family photo in place of white area.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the suggestion it helped a lot!

Comment: "imagine family photo in place of white area." Why not just use that image as the mask? You'd probably need to call whiteThresholdImage on it, and then use `$img2->compositeImage($opacity, \Imagick::COMPOSITE_COPYOPACITY, 0, 0);` or similar..... I see no need to going via paths for this.

Comment: You can use XML parser to get the path

Comment: SimpleXML is a good XML parser